# php eliminar datos

Tags: php, html

Buenas estoy intentando eliminar datos desde php a mysql pero no lo consigo.No da ninguna fallo pero no funciona.

aquí muestro los datos y creo un botón para eliminar los datos

```
  <?php
    while($variable = $consulta->fetch_assoc())
    {

      ?>
      <tr>

    <td><?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['apellido']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['correo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['contrasena']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="acciones.php?accion=consultaeli&nombre=<?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?>">

          <input name="btneliminar" type="button" value="Eliminar" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" />
      </form>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php

}
?>
```

y aqui tengo el php para eliminar

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bbdd");
    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $conexion->connect_error;
    }
    else{

        $accion=$_POST["accion"];
        switch($accion)
        {
            case "consultaeli":

                $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];

                header("Location: usuarios.php"); //pagina desde la que se hace la llamada

                $borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where nombre='$nombre'"

                mysqli_query($conexion, $borrar);
                mysqli_close($conexion);
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo para mandar los datos al arhivo que procesa la consulta tienes algo así

```
<form method="post" action="acciones.php?accion=consultaeli&nombre=<?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?>">
```

¿por que no pruebas agregando los datos en inputs type hidden?
Y tambien quitar los dos types en el submit, no es necesario, al darle el type submit, el navegador lo mostrara como un botón e incluso lo puedes personalizar con css

```
<?php
while($variable = $consulta->fetch_assoc())
{

  ?>
  <tr>

<td><?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $variable['apellido']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $variable['correo']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $variable['contrasena']; ?></td>
<td>
  <form method="post" action="acciones.php">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="consultaeli">
       <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $variable['nombre'];?>">             
      <input name="btneliminar" type="button" value="Eliminar" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" />
  </form>

</td>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_query' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPBLlocal\acciones.php on line 19 Ahora me sale ese fallo que hace referencia a esto del php mysqli_query($conexion, $borrar);

Comment: es por que en  la linea  $borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where nombre='$nombre'" te falta el punto y coma

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que pasa es que estas tratando de acceder a los parámetros a través de $_POST cuando los parámetros de la url se obtienen a través de $_GET.

Si deseas usar $_POST deberías guardar los valores en campos de formulario, como .

```
<input type="hidden" name ="accion" value="consultaeli"/>
<input type="hidden" name ="nombre" value="<?php echo $variable['nombre'];?>"/>
```

De todos modos no tiene caso usar el metodo POST si los parámetros los vas a pasar en la url, te recomiendo cambiar a GET.

**Un detalle, no se si sea válido usar dos types en el boton submit**

Comment: He probado con gente y tampoco funciona

Comment: Ya has intentado cambiar el metodo a get?

Comment: si,cambie a get todos los post y sigue sin funciona,no hace nada

Comment: hablo de cambiar method="POST" a method ="GET" tambien

Comment: sisi,hice esos cambios y no funciona